# Utilizing Open Closed Principle (SOLID)

Tags: c#, solid-principles, open-closed-principle

I've seen couple of samples for SOLID Open Close Principle. And those explanations are usually pretty clear.

But there is still 1 more question in my mind, which is how do we initialize those different classes without using the conditional statement?

Here is the sample code:

```
public enum PreferredMeal
{
    Vegetarian = 1,
    NonVegetarian = 2
}

public class Customer
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public PreferredMeal PreferredMeal { get; set; }
}

public interface IMealGenerator
{
    List<Meal> GenerateMeals(Customer customer);
}

public class VegetarianMealGenerator : IMealGenerator
{
    public override List<Meal> GenerateMeals(Customer customer)
    {
        // Some codes here
    }
}

public class NonVegetarianMealGenerator : IMealGenerator
{
    public override List<Meal> GenerateMeals(Customer customer)
    {
        // Some codes here
    }
}
```

If let say I am given the following data and I was asked to read this data and generate meals for all the customers.

```
Input(CustomerName, PreferredMeal):

Customer1,1
Customer2,1
Customer3,2
```

Aren't we gonna use if statement as well to identify which class that implements MealGenerator to be instantiated according to the customer, like the following?

```
// Let's assume this function is called after all customers data has been read
// And those data is passed here
public void GenerateCustomerMeals(List<Customer> customers)
{
    foreach (var customer in customers)
    {
        if (customer.PreferredMeal == PreferredMeal.Vegetarian)
            new VegetarianMealGenerator().GenerateMeals(customer);
        else if (customer.PreferredMeal == PreferredMeal.NonVegetarian)
            new NonVegetarianMealGenerator().GenerateMeals(customer);
    }
}
```

If this is the case, then GenerateCustomerMeals seems to not satisfy the open close principle. Is there a better SOLID way to do this? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how do we initialize those different classes without using the conditional statement?

The conditional statement is not evil. It's necessary when we need to map some conditions (PreferredMeal in your example) to the corresponding implementations(IMealGenerator interface), so is `switch` statement.

The problem in your code is that you are building implementations of `IMealGenerator` in the method where it will be used. That's incorrect, because in most circumstances you will have a few methods like `GenerateCustomerMeals`. These methods, shouldn't know how to map `PreferredMeal` to an implementation of `IMealGenerator`. The only class knows the mapping is a `MealGeneratorFactory` like this:

```
class MealGeneratorFactory : IMealGeneratorFactory 
{
    IMealGenerator GetMealGenerator(Customer customer)
    {
        // if/switch here
    }
}
```

And all your methods like `GenerateCustomerMeals` depends on `IMealGeneratorFactory`, gets an `IMealGenerator` and uses it.

Dependency injection will make things easier, but the conclusions are the same.

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple implementations, and you need to switch between them, one option is to provide an additional implementation that allows you to switch between them. In this way SOLID is still preserved, as the routing mechanism is concealed from the consuming code.

```
public class RoutingMealGenerator : MealGenerator
{
   public override List<Meal> GenerateMeals(Customer customer)
   {
      if (customer.PreferredMeal == PreferredMeal.Vegetarian)
         return new VegetarianMealGenerator().GenerateMeals(customer);
      else if (customer.PreferredMeal == PreferredMeal.NonVegetarian)
         return new NonVegetarianMealGenerator().GenerateMeals(customer);
   }
}
```

A better option yet is to use a dependency injection framework, such as [Autofac](https://autofac.org/), that supports [implementation selection based on keys](http://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/keyed-services.html).

This can allow for services to be registered separately against each key, and then a service lookup arrangement such as:

```
public class PreferenceRoutingMealGenerator : MealGenerator
{
   IIndex<PreferredMeal, MealGenerator> _serviceLookup;

   public PreferenceRoutingMealGenerator( IIndex<PreferredMeal, MealGenerator> serviceLookup )
   {
      _serviceLookup = serviceLookup;
   }

   public override List<Meal> GenerateMeals(Customer customer)
   {
      MealGenerator gen = _serviceLookup[customer.PreferredMeal];

      return gen.GenerateMeals(customer);
   }
}
```